# node.js elasticsearch self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, ssl

I've been trying to learn elasticsearch and decided to try to connect it with node.js. I have a elasticsearch running + a index I created named test-idx. I'm following the documentation of elasticsearch to connect and create a document however when I run my code I get 'ConnectionError: self signed certificate in certificate chain' followed by a huge meta object.

```
const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    node: 'https://localhost:9200',
    auth: {
      username: 'elastic',
      password: '123456'
    }
})

client.index({
    index: 'test-idx',
    document: {
        field: 'test123'
    }
  })
```

I tried adding when creating the instance of the Client but it didn't seem to help

```
tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm my case it's Working. I'm using node with nest js

`tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false }`

Answer (score 0):

instead of accepting unauthorized when auth provided, you can create a certificate for elasticsearch and include that in your nestjs app.

By default cert file reside wherever elastic setup is:
eg. `elasticsearch/config/certs/http_ca.crt`

if you are using dockerized one, copy like this to outside of container:

`docker cp <elastic-container-name>:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/http_ca.crt .`

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

const certificatePath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), '<path-to-your-crt-file-from-app-root');

...
 auth: {
        username: 'elastic',
        password: 'password'
      },
      tls: {
        ca: fs.readFileSync(certificatePath)
      }
...
```